# How to make ActiveRecord access a table from a dblink (correctly)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, activerecord, dblink

I am developing a RoR project using an Oracle database. Recently I added a DBLink to another database and this works perfectly just from an SQL.
When I want to add the table to my class with the following code...

```
class ServerModel < ActiveRecord::Base 
  set_table_name "S985.S985_947_MODELS_VW@R985_A947.WORLD"
  set_primary_key "model_barcode"

  acts_as_reportable
  acts_as_entity
end
```

... I get this error:

```
NativeException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02084: database name is missing a component
: select * from (SELECT "S985"."S985_947_MODELS_VW"@"R985_A947"."WORLD".* FROM "S985"."S985_947_MODELS_VW"@"R985_A947"."WORLD"  ) where rownum <= 14
```

Of course this automatically used query does not work. It shouldn't select `"S985"."S985_947_MODELS_VW"@"R985_A947"."WORLD".*` but just `"S985"."S985_947_MODELS_VW".*`, without duplicating the name of the dblink (@R985_947.WORLD).

Is this possible with the `set_table_name` method or any other `ActiveRecord` method?

The answer looks simple, but I cannot find the solution. Can anybody help me with this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure about tweaking Active Record to include the DB Link name, but what about creating a view of the remote table, something like:

```
create or replace view S985_947_MODELS_VW
as
select * from S985_947_MODELS_VW"@"R985_A947"."WORLD"
```

And then just accessing the view in the ROR application?  Not sure if the view can be inserted, updated etc - you would need to check that out.  I have a feeling a 'simple' view (ie one on a single table without group by etc) can be updated and inserted into.

Comment: I only have one more problem:my default_scope has a malformed query string error %'. My method is:   default_scope :conditions => ["FULLNAME like '/IT INFRASTRUCTURE/HARDWARE/SERVER/PHYSICAL/\%' OR FULLNAME like '/IT INFRASTRUCTURE/HARDWARE/OTHER/\%'"]

 I am using a % as a wildcard.

Comment: Can you see the actual query string it is generating behind the scenes of the named_scope, or is it erroring before it even gets to that point?

Comment: I already found the solution. using "FULLNAME like ? OR FULLNAME like ?, '/IT INFRASTRUCTURE/HARDWARE/SERVER/PHYSICAL/\%', '/IT INFRASTRUCTURE/HARDWARE/OTHER/\%'" strangely does the job. Still thanks though!

Comment: Sorry to bring this question back up again, but have you found a database link solution? I cannot create views or tables in my current DB config

Answer (score -1):

Is `establish_connection` what you're looking for?

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class

You can use this to set class-specific connections for Models you choose.